# How to map browser locale to one of my php gettext i18n locales?

Tags: php, internationalization, locale

I've started using gettext to translate my site.  So far I've translated key menus and headings into French, Spanish and Portuguese.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
.../locale
    /en_GB.utf8
        /LC_MESSAGES
            messages.po
            messages.mo
    /fr_FR.utf8
        /LC_MESSAGES
            messages.po
            messages.mo
    /es_ES.utf8
        /LC_MESSAGES
            messages.po
            messages.mo
    /pt_PT.utf8
        /LC_MESSAGES
            messages.po
            messages.mo
```

I can get the user's default browser locale like so:

```
$locale = Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
```

If their locale is `en_GB`, `fr_FR`, `es_ES` or `pt_PT` this works perfectly, I just append the locale with `.utf8` and I'm good to go.

But a locale might not be set at all.  Hmmm, ok, so we'll add this:

```
if (!$locale) {
    $locale = 'en_GB';
}
```

But I'm aware that a locale might be simply `fr` (and maybe `FR`?).  No problem, this will catch most of them:

```
if (strlen($locale)==2) {
    $locale = strtolower($locale).'_'.strtoupper($locale);
}
```

OK, fine.  But the code is starting to increase, and now I see that apparently `french` is a valid locale.  And probably countless other weird edge cases that I don't know about.

What's the *right* way to do this?

Upon looking at the documentation, one might think that `Locale::lookup` would hold the answer, but sadly not:

```
var_dump(Locale::lookup(['en_GB','fr_FR','es_ES','pt_PT'], 'fr'));     // ''
var_dump(Locale::lookup(['en_GB','fr_FR','es_ES','pt_PT'], 'fr_FR'));  // 'fr_FR'
var_dump(Locale::lookup(['en_GB','fr_FR','es_ES','pt_PT'], 'fr_CA'));  // ''
var_dump(Locale::lookup(['en_GB','fr_FR','es_ES','pt_PT'], 'french')); // ''

var_dump(Locale::lookup(['en','fr','es','pt'], 'fr'));                 // 'fr'
var_dump(Locale::lookup(['en','fr','es','pt'], 'fr_FR'));              // 'fr'
var_dump(Locale::lookup(['en','fr','es','pt'], 'fr_CA'));              // 'fr'
var_dump(Locale::lookup(['en','fr','es','pt'], 'french'));             // ''
```